# On the spectral sequence.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, spectral-sequences

To the best of my knowledge, the spectral sequence $E_1^{p,q} \Rightarrow E^{\bullet}$, or $E_2^{p,q} \Rightarrow E^{\bullet}$ is constructed from the double complex. On the other hand, there is another construction via triangular diagram as follows$\colon$
\begin{equation*}
A \Longrightarrow B \Longrightarrow C \Longrightarrow A[1].
\end{equation*}

I learned this before in Nottingham, but I cannot remember this approach, and what these $A, B$, and $C$ are.

### Q. Are the construction of the spectral sequence via a certain traingular complexes and via a double complex equivalent?

Comment: I think by 'triangle' you mean exact couple? https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+couple